# HoloView Scatter groupby with plot width and height option

Tags: holoviews

import holoviews as hv

renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')

scatter = hv.Scatter(df,kdims=['X','Y'],vdims=['A','B']).opts(plot=dict(width=1200,height=900))
renderer.save(scatter,'out')

I get the out.html with the correct width and height.

When I add 
scatter.groupby(['A'])

I loose the plot dimensions that I specified. It defaults a small value.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried groupby in the same line:

`scatter = hv.Scatter(df, kdims=['X','Y'],vdims=['A','B'], groupby=['A']).opts(plot=dict(width=1200,height=900))
renderer.save(scatter,'out')`

You might not even need to specify 'A' in vdims:

`scatter = hv.Scatter(df, kdims=['X','Y'],vdims=['B'], groupby=['A']).opts(plot=dict(width=1200,height=900))
renderer.save(scatter,'out')`